# rxjs subscribe in ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Button show triggered on ngIf in template. After this code the button is not shown.

```
 public navBackVisible = false
        ngOnInit() {
                this.router.events
                  //.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                  //.pipe(pairwise())
                  .subscribe(
                  () => this.navBackVisible = true); // here true
        
              console.log(this.navBackVisible); // here false
    }
```

template:

```
 <button *ngIf = "navBackVisible"><icon>arrow_back</icon></button>
```

UPD:

- this is all code
- ChangeDetection.Default
- router emmits events
- function inside subscribe is called
- function inside subscribe fires before ngIf
- But `this.http.get(url).subscribe(() => this.navBackVisible = true)` works fine
- **everything works** if I write the same logic in the constructor of some service and call it from this component

Comment: Something else changed it - no way to tell by this. Please share rest of the relevant code.

Comment: navBackVisible is set to true inside an async subscription, so the console log triggers before the sub returns a value. Once the subscription resolves, it's set to true, but the console log line is already read and won't be read again.

Comment: @MishaMashina I know it. My button is not rendered in the template.

Comment: @JoosepParts This is all code

Comment: It looks like your are using `ChangeDetection.OnPush`, isn't? If that's the case you shouldn't be updating the `navBackVisible` flag like that ;)

Comment: @guzmanoj Unfortunately I tried different ones but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Pairwise (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise), only emitting value(s) if and only if after at least one value has been emitted, and router events here is only emitting 1 value and then completed.

Comment: My button is not rendered without both pipes in the code

Comment: So maybe your router events does not get emitted. Use tap after and before instanfe of NavigationEnd

Comment: When I wrote "here true" in code, I meant that I checked it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `pairwise()` and `filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)` at the same time. Choose one or the other because `pairwise` emits previous and current value in pairs. If you filter out the last router event (which is NaviationEnd event) your `pairwise` never emits and you never fall into function to turn `this.navBackVisible = true`. At least, that's my understanding of this (if I am mistaken please correct me).

Use:

```js
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('i am here');
        this.navBackVisible = true;
      });
```

Comment: I specifically commented out my lines in the code, but you still paid attention to them. My button is not rendered without both pipes in the code. When I wrote "here true" in code, I meant that I checked it in the debugger. function inside subscribe is called fine.

Answer (score 0):

**As a result**, ngOnInit called the getter variable from the service-class. And in the service in the constructor, I used the same logic. **Everything works.** A little later I changed the variable to sessionStorage (it fits my logic). I still don't know what it was. If this happens to someone, then this is a good step towards finding a problem. This solution satisfied my problem, but the question is still open, I will follow the answers and answer your clarifications.